# Document Sharing - Collaboration - Version Control Tools

Tags: svn, version-control, collaboration, dropbox, document-management

I'm trying to come up with a decent solution for my company to share and control various files - from source code, to media files, to documentation and what not. In general, it looks like there are good solutions for all of these existing - but I'm looking for a centralized one, and cannot find it yet.

My requirements list: must be stable, with clients available for all 3 (Win/Mac/Linux), have version control and be easy to use. And did I mention MUST be easy to use? Bonus points if the whole thing is easy to backup to an offsite location.

Tried Novell's iFolder, which seems more or less fine for media and docs, but from what I see it lacks version control and does not plan to add that any time soon. Also not suitable for code control.

Tried Wordpress for docs - it does have version control for docs you create from within it, but things like source code and media files are obviously not handled well.

Seriously considering SVN - it is well supported by IDEs we use and would be a perfect fit really, but it does not score highly in the easy of use department. Outside of code control - we need it dead simple so even an accountant can use it ;).

Are there any tools that might make using subversion easy for the less technical folks? I hear mixed things about most Windows GUI clients, including TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further reading I see that you reference code as well,, in that case Just get on with it and use git, there are fine tools on all platforms now tortoise git, on Win and Linux, and you "can" manage a master central repo as canonical. Using other lesser tools will eventually just be an anchor.. You don't have to get into all the esoterica if you and your users don't need it but having it for the future does not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I use VisualSVN and like it quite a bit.  Seems easy to me but not sure how it would rank for an accountant.

Keep in mind that if you use a tool that is designed for the technology industry it is likely that non-technical people may have some troubles with it...

If you really need document management with version control AND a source control system you might consider two separate systems.  Do you really want accountants mucking around in your source code?

Comment: well, accountants and programmers would obvious have different repositories, but a single system would still simplify maintenance, backups, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Google docs? it does all you are asking.. The revision tracking has just become quite awesome,, I have not tried the MS office integration tool but it might help if you need to keep some stuff native to Office...

Comment: It is indeed quite good for docs of all kinds, but the fact that it's online makes some people weary. Backup is also - kind of built in, kind of not there.